# How should I approach adding a feature to the Java language?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jls

I've seen a few neat features in other languages around Java like generators and the recent "await" feature, and I tried to implement some of them using bytecode manipulation. However, I think these are neat enough for most developers to make them a language feature. I've seen the kijaro project; however, there seems to be very little documentation on how to get on there. So, even if only for my own use and curiousity, how should I approach doing so?

Thanks!

Comment: I came across this a few months ago [Roman Numerals in Java](http://www.iam.unibe.ch/~akuhn/blog/2008/roman-numerals-in-your-java/). I never really chased it up but it looks intriguing.

Comment: Closed as off-topic? I think this question conforms with the line "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession", and does not apply to any of the "don't do". This question is about how to deal with a real programming problem, as I do need reference to how to start getting my hands on source code/examples/whatever to get this thing done.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: That article was interesting, and so were a few of its links - but they all seemed to "hack" into the compiler.. But I'll give it a few more looks soon.

Comment: Why modify the bytecode, when you can invent nice syntax, and then transform to standard syntax? Check out Wikipedia "Program Transformation Systems": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation  (PS: if you like this question, Vote to Reopen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the article entitled ["So you want to change the Java Programming Language..."](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/so_you_want_to_change) on Oracle's blog.

Comment: I probably should have said that on the question. I have looked at it; it's from 2007; it points to broken links; and when you DO find the real links, its the kijaro project. It's really no good on explaining what I should DO within that project.

Comment: Check out the Java Community Process: http://jcp.org/en/procedures/overview. Also you can get the current source for the javac compiler (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7) if you just want to play around with implementing new features.